# access denied for python command os.system

Tags: python-2.7, access-denied, os.system

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOaWo.gif)i would like to fix te problem of "access denied" message when trying to execute a windwos dos command from python script. in my case the command is the unix grep  that i copied to the windows/system32 directory. the grep command works fine under windows system once placed under thhe system32 directory.

> > > import os
> > >       cmd="grep lucy D:\tool\webmailloghandling\globalaccex.log > D:\tool\webmailloghandling\t.log"
> > >       returned_value = os.system(cmd)
> > >       Accès refusé.

Comment: You need to format your question so it's clear what parts are quotes from what. StackOverflow uses markdown for formatting, it's a nice system. You also need to add enough context to your question so that people can _easily_ understand what you're trying to do and how. I also suggest phrasing your question _as an explicit question_, either at the beginning or end of the post.

Comment: grep is not available on Windows, unless you have MinGW tools in your PATH. What are you actually trying to do? You could implement a "grep" in Python, it just depends what your end goal is. The "Access Denied" message means you do not have read permissions on the directory you're trying to access.

Comment: regarding the grep command i copied the unix tools under system32 directory so i get all the unix commad under my windows machine as if i was using a unix machine. for the permission issue. i added the needed permission to the directory webmailloghandling (read an write) but still geting the access denied error.